# How to check whether R is already installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am newbie to R and I think I previously installed R but not sure.

Is there any way to know whether R is installed in your system?

Comment: Are you looking for something other than "try to launch R and see if it works"

Comment: And searching the system might also help

Comment: I have not installed R-studio.Just **R**.

Comment: Then open the terminal and type `R` on the command line.

Comment: Perfectly valid question.

Comment: Obviously it's a valid question. Such unfriendly comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to summarize a few answers from the comments with less snark...

1. typing `R` into the command line might bring it up. If that doesn't work, R is *probably* not installed.
2. R might be in `/usr/bin/`. Look in that folder. If not, there's an even slimmer chance that you have R.
3. Search for a file named R otherwise.

Answer (score 29):

On ubuntu I would typically use the `which` command to check for existance of a program.
`which` is a Unix command used to identify the location of executables. If the R executable is somewhere in the `PATH` then it should return its location:

```
john@ubuntu:~$ which R
/usr/bin/R
```

Alternatively you can use the `type` command:

```
john@ubuntu:~$ type R
R is /usr/bin/R
```

`type` is a Unix command that describes how its arguments would be interpreted if used as command names.

failing `R` being on the `PATH` you could resort to `locate` which would be faster then `find` however it will most likely give you a large number of returns for `R` so some filtering would be required:

```
john@ubuntu:~$ locate -b R | fgrep -w R/bin
/usr/lib/R/bin/R
/usr/lib/R/bin/REMOVE
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rcmd
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rd2pdf
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rdconv
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rdiff
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rprof
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```